# How do I solve this case of "type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'int'" and type 'int' is not a subtype of type 'String'

Tags: flutter

My problem is that when the program tries to do the ListView, it gives me that error. And when i define it as String, it gives the same error, but backwards. That's the main reason why there are logs everywhere. Here is the code:

Model:

```
// To parse this JSON data, do
//
//     final facturasDeVenta = facturasDeVentaFromJson(jsonString);

import 'dart:convert';

FacturasDeVenta facturasDeVentaFromJson(String str) =>
    FacturasDeVenta.fromJson(json.decode(str));

String facturasDeVentaToJson(FacturasDeVenta data) =>
    json.encode(data.toJson());

class FacturasDeVenta {
  int count;
  int totalCount;
  List<VtaPedG> vtaPedGs;

  FacturasDeVenta({
    required this.count,
    required this.totalCount,
    required this.vtaPedGs,
  });

  factory FacturasDeVenta.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) =>
      FacturasDeVenta(
        count: json["count"],
        totalCount: json["total_count"],
        vtaPedGs: List<VtaPedG>.from(
            json["vta_ped_g"].map((x) => VtaPedG.fromJson(x))),
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "count": count,
        "total_count": totalCount,
        "vtaPedGs": List<dynamic>.from(vtaPedGs.map((x) => x.toJson())),
      };
}

class VtaPedG {
  int id;
  int clt;
  int emp;

  VtaPedG({
    required this.id,
    required this.clt,
    required this.emp,
  });

  factory VtaPedG.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => VtaPedG(
        id: int.parse(json["id"]),
        clt: int.parse(json["clt"]),
        emp: int.parse(json["emp"]),
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "id": id,
        "clt": clt,
        "emp": emp,
      };
}
```

The part that shows it:

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:developer';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import "package:velneoapp/api/api_model.dart";

class PartesView extends StatefulWidget {
  const PartesView({super.key});

  @override
  State<PartesView> createState() => _PartesViewState();
}

class _PartesViewState extends State<PartesView> {
  bool _isLoaded = true;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _getData();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    _getData();
  }

  FacturasDeVenta? dataFromAPI;
  _getData() async {
    try {
      String url =
          "https://demoapi.velneo.com/verp-api/vERP_2_dat_dat/v1/vta_ped_g?page%5Bsize%5D=20&fields=id,clt,emp&api_key=api123";
      http.Response res = await http.get(Uri.parse(url));
      log("${res.statusCode}");
      if (res.statusCode == 200) {
        print("jiji");
        dataFromAPI = await FacturasDeVenta.fromJson(json.decode(res.body));
        _isLoaded = false;
        setState(() {});
      } else {
        throw ("NONOAAAAAAA");
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print("NONO");
      log(e.toString());
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text("Partes"),
      ),
      body: _isLoaded
          ? const Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
            )
          : ListView.builder(
              scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
              itemCount: 10,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  child: Row(
                    children: [
                      Text("\$${dataFromAPI!.vtaPedGs[index].id.toString()}"),
                      Text("\$${dataFromAPI!.vtaPedGs[index].clt.toString()}"),
                    ],
                  ),
                );
              },
            ),
    );
  }
}
```

I tried searching for an answer, but every case is diferent than mine. It's my first time coding some Rest API code, so maybe that's the reason.

If anybody can please tell me why, because I can't find an answer that I have to adequate the code to.

Comment: The error says that somewhere a variable is expecting a int value and you are giving it a string, i think the model must having the issue. Can you check that all the variable types and proper as per the api response.

Comment: Also could you specify which line gives you the problem?

Comment: I don't know the exact line which gives me the problem, I was trying to find it, but the exception only says that. Srry I'm somewhat new to coding.

Oh, and the variable types. How can I check what types the API call asks me to put?

Comment: Welp, I have checked the variables. It was EMP, that even though I gave me only numbers, it was String. So... Yeah, solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see that in the api response, you are getting data as below

```
"count": 20,
  "total_count": 20071,
  "vta_ped_g": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "clt": 4789,
      "emp": "001"
    },
   ]
```

And in your model, you are parsing the `emp` as `int`. Change the type to `String` and it should work.

```
class VtaPedG {
  int id;
  int clt;
  String emp;   <--- Changed this from int to String

  VtaPedG({
    required this.id,
    required this.clt,
    required this.emp,
  });

  factory VtaPedG.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => VtaPedG(
        id: int.parse(json["id"]),
        clt: int.parse(json["clt"]),
        emp: json["emp"],
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "id": id,
        "clt": clt,
        "emp": emp,
      };
}
```

Comment: Yup, that was the answer. Thx a lot.